# Best practice to set up qt application that works for different DPI

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on a Qt application, Linux platform, in which the dimensions (e.g. height and length) are hardcoded in pixels. This makes the application work perfectly for one device, but it does not scale properly to higher resolution/dpi devices.

Since this would be nice in the near future, I'am looking for alternative methods. From the Qt website I effectively find two different opportunities:

- Use the High DPI scaling functionality (introduced in Qt 5.6) (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html)
- Use QtLayout and scale children with respect to their parents. (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/scalability.html)

I don't quite understand when to choose one above the other. It seems to me that existing applications are most easily dealt with using the first option since this option does not require to change the application code.
But what method is preferred when starting a Qt application from scratch? Should you ideally disable the High DPI scaling (Qt::AA_DisableHighDpiScaling) and use QtLayout and QtQuick? Is Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling just meant as a quick fix for existing applications, or is it the way to go with new applications as well?

Comment: Always use layouts (anchoring etc), High DPI only relevant if your target is a high DPI screen.

Comment: The target concerns a high DPI target. Why should this only be relevant for high DPI targets? Qt's High DPI mode works , like OS X , with independent pixels cordinate system; scaling the hardcoded pixels with the ratio between device pixels and independent pixels. Therefore any change in DPI should be scaled by Qt when this mode is enabled.